# Safari opacity animation sometimes fails

Tags: safari, css-animations, mobile-safari

*update: I've found a workaround for this, see my own answer.*

I have an animation that crossfades back and forth between two images, by changing the opacity of one image that is placed directly on top of the other.

#### Symptoms:

It works fine it all browsers.

It occasionally stops working after a while in Safari - typically  permanently stuck on the opening image, or you see two or three frames midway through the fade with the rest skipped, occasionally you'll get a flash between the two states without any animation.

Occurs significantly more frequent on mobile.  Either way always cleared by restarting the browser, but often **not** by reloading tabs. *Sometimes* fixed by navigating a new page then using the back button.

---

I've used `will-change: opacity` on both images, it doesn't help.

I didn't notice this problem when I was animating the same graphics by changing a single background image URL - but the problem with *that* was it's not supported in Firefox…

The images are scaled down in the browser - the full size is 1200x1200 in a frame roughly 400x400 - though that doesn't seem excessive, and they've been compressed.

They need to be within a grid because of the layout of the rest of the page (using `position: absolute` wouldn't give them height.)

#### Simplified HTML and CSS:

```
@keyframes crossfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.6% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
<img class="start-frame" src="square-start-1200.jpg">
<img class="end-frame" src="square-end-1200.jpg">
```

```
     /* within a div that has display: grid... */

     img {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        will-change: opacity;
      }

      img.start-frame {
        z-index: 1;
      }

      img.end-frame {
        /* placed on top of the start image, but needs to be hidden to begin with */
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;

        animation: crossfade linear 20s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }
```

#### Affected browsers

- Safari 14.1.2 on Mojave 10.14.6
- iPhone 6S with iOS 14.7.1
- iPad Mini 5th Gen with iOS 14.7.1
- iPod Touch 7th Gen with iOS 13.7

Answer (score 1):

A workaround - run the animation in reverse:

```
animation-direction: reverse;
```

As it's symmetrically in this case, it doesn't matter.

I can't explain it, but touch wood this has proved stable on Safari 14.1.2 on Mojave, and on both iOS 13 (iPod) and iOS 14 on (iPhone and iPad) in normal daily use, with backgrounding the tabs, refreshing them, sleep/wake cycles etc.

I did also try making the animation start at 5% rather than 0 (i.e. having `opacity: 0` at both the 0% and 5% marks, but was only changing the direction that seemed to have an immediate effect.)

Adding `animation-delay` (in the hope dropped/stuttering frames might be somehow related to an image that hadn't finished loading) didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `webkit` property I think It works Fine check below Ex.

```
     img {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        will-change: opacity;
      }

      img.start-frame {
        z-index: 1;
      }

      img.end-frame {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        -webkit-animation: crossfade linear 20s infinite;
        animation: crossfade linear 20s infinite;
      }
```